# Getting Azure Devops NPM feed Authentication Token from CLI

Tags: azure-devops, npm-install

I am using azure devops to host an authenticated NPM feed.  I would like to generate a token to access that feed using the CLI.  The instructions on azure devops involve going through the web interface to generate a personal access token (PAT), then base64-ing that token, and adding it to the .npmrc.  If I do that, I'm able to run `npm install` against that feed without issue.

In the CLI, I've tried using `az account get-access-token`, grabbing that token, and encoding it.  But that seems to fail, and I guess that makes sense because it is a token for azure itself, not azure devops.

Does anyone have any guidance on how this could be done?  Am I stuck doing it manually?

Answer (score 1):

[az account get-access-token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-get-access-token) get a token for utilities to **access Azure**.

It's not Azure DevOps.

We also have an [az devops CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/devops?view=azure-cli-latest) command. But we could not be able to get/create  a token through this. Neither does Rest API.

You'll **have to manually create** the PAT token from web interface in your Azure DevOps Organization.

Comment: I agree that it kind of makes sense that `az account get-access-token` applies to azure, not azure devops.  But interestingly, I CAN use that access token with the authenticated nuget feed provider.

Comment: Hi @JakeStevenson Thanks for the sharing. Have you also give a test with the token `az account get-access-token` on some other areas such as Git command, build ? Will it also work with them? If not, I am afraid, it's something special with nuget feed side.